# Readonly EntityManager

Tags: caching, jpa, entitymanager

I see, that EntityManager copies query results entities to local cache unless query hinted as ReadOnly. Is it possible to make EntityManager read-only with all queries and use only shared L2 cache ?

Comment: "unless query hinted as ReadOnly" ... presumably you're referring to some specific JPA implementation here, because there is NO generic "hint"

Answer (score 0):

I refer to [EclipseLink](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/q_read_only.htm): 
"@QueryHint(name = QueryHints.READ_ONLY, value = HintValues.TRUE)"